# Deleting multiple paths in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm creating a collaborative drawing app using Fabric.  Due to the nature of this app, it's better for people to delete all of their lines at once than to implement some sort of undo/erase functionality.

I've tried iterating over the list of `path`s, like so:

```
canvas.getObjects().forEach((path) => {
  if(path.senderId === client.id){
    canvas.remove(path);
  }
});

// Or

let paths = canvas.getObjects().filter(path => path.senderId === client.id);

while(paths.length) {
  canvas.remove(paths[0]);
}
```

The first one doesn't work, since removing the path modifies the length of the array (as discussed [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/148)).  However, the second one runs forever and I'm not sure why.

If this is the wrong approach, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Removing the path from the canvas won't change the length of your filtered path array.

Comment: @Pointy well, that was a brainfart.  I'll make sure that works when I'm home, but I bet that's the case.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, `getObjects()` returns a reference to the internal array managed by the library. However when you use `.filter()` like that, you end up with a *new* array.

Answer (score 1):

one nice and concise way is to do:

```
canvas.getObjects('path').forEach((path) => {
  if(path.senderId === client.id){
    canvas.remove(path);
  }
});
```

In this way getObjects will return a new array and you should be able to remove them without getting mad with which array you are working on.

I believe getObjects() should always return a shallow copy for easy handling of those situations. If someone has some performance concerns can still access canvas._objects directly.

Comment: Interesting!  So `getObjects` will modify in-place if you don't add an argument, but will create a new array if you do?

Comment: yes if you read the source, getObects return the array directly or a filtered version of it